# "if" query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I want to create query follow.

```
select member.name,depratment.name from member 
left join depratment on depratment.dep_id=member.dep_id
if(member.position_id=1){
 where member.ages>50; 
}
else{
where member.salary>50000;
}
```

Help me? Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't need `IF` on this. You just need a compound condition. Try,

```
SELECT..
FROM..
WHERE (member.position_id =  1 AND member.ages   > 50   ) OR
      (member.position_id <> 1 AND member.salary > 50000)
```

Comment: John, `WHERE (member.position_id=1 AND member.ages>50) OR (member.salary>50000)` is not _quite_ the same thing, think of someone aged 45 on $60K salary with a position id of 1. Your query would include them, the original wouldn't. I've updated your answer so that it matches exactly.

Comment: @TomDyThai what do you really want to do? you can't use `IF` to separate your condition in where clause. there is also called `inline ifclause`.